# Prove that $f(x)=2x+[x]+\text{sin}x\text{cos}x$ is one to one and onto

Tags: calculus, functions

Given a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined as  $f(x)=2x+[x]+\text{sin}x\text{cos}x$, I need to confirm if it's one to one and onto.

I checked for the monotonicity by differentiating the function to get $f'(x)=2+cos2x>0$ (here I took differentiation of $[x]=0$) and confirmed that it's increasing since $\text{cos}2x$ has a range of $[-1,1]$ and hence is one one .

How do I check for onto here? Is it valid to say that since $[x]$ is discontinuous my $f(xn)$ will also be discontinuous, I am not sure if this statement is always correct, so please explain this or some other method to explain why it will be an onto function.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos  Is it ok now? I have edited it

Comment: Yes, it is better. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please explain what $[x]$ means. Is it the fractional part?

Comment: @emanresu it is greatest integer function

Comment: 1) Your calculation of $f'$ does not prove that $f$ is increasing, because $f$ is not differentiable (not even continuous) at integer points. 2) Yes, a sum of a continuous function and a discontinuous one is discontinuous. 3) You should edit your post to specify the domain and codomain of $f.$

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+2x%2B%5Clfloor+x%5Crfloor%2B%5Csin+x%5Ccos+x%2C+x+from+-0.5+to+2.5

Comment: @AnneBauval I have now specified the domain codomain.For one one should I then use the logic that if f(x1)=f(x2) implies x1=x2 then the function is one one, or is this type of question to be done based on the graph of the function?

Comment: For one-to-one you just have to complete your "$f'>0$ at non-integer points" with "the jump of $f$ at integer points is $>0.$ For (non!-) surjectivity, look at the link above to WolframAlpha plot. Or simply realize that $f$ is increasing and has these positive jumps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one-to-one by monotonicity,  you just have to complete your "$f′>0$
at non-integer points" with "the jump of $f$
at integer points is $>0$".

For (non!-) surjectivity, look at the link (given in comments) to WolframAlpha's plot. Or simply realize that $f$
is increasing and has these positive jumps.

Answer (score 0):

It is not onto.
At each integer n, f is not continuous.
There is some gap at these points,

e.g. f(1)=2+1+$\sin 1 \cos 1$

There is no $x\in\mathbb{R}$, such that $f(x)=2+0.5+\sin 1 \cos 1$

Answer (score 0):

The function $h(t)=2t+\sin t$ is strictly increasing, as $h'(t)=2+\cos t\ge 1.$ Thus the function $${1\over 2}h(2x)=2x+{1\over 2}\sin (2x)=2x+\sin x\cos x$$
is strictly increasing. The sum of a strictly increasing function and a nondecreasing function is strictly increasing. Therefore $f(x)={1\over 2}h(2x)+[x]$ is strictly increasing. Every strictly increasing function is onto iff it is continuous. As $f(x)$  is discontinuous at all integer points it cannot be onto.  More explicitly $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)= -1,\quad \lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0$$ Hence $f(x)$ does not admit values from $(-1,0).$